# getting percentage of values meeting conditions within a Pandas group by

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe of of `People`, `Days`, and `Types`. The data doesn't really make sense, it's just an example.

I'd like to do a group by first on `People` then `Type` and then find the percentage of Days that are less than or equal to 3.

In order to do this, I am created a `Boolean` column for equal or under 3 days. Then applying a `count` and `sum` aggregate. I'm not a big fan of this method because I really only need the `count` for the `Days` column and `sum` for the `Under Day Limit` column. This method is essentially creating two unnecessary columns and creates a number of extra steps. How can I clean this code up so it runs more efficiently over my larger dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', 4, 'Type 1'],
                        ['A', 1, 'Type 1'],
                        ['A', 3, 'Type 2'],
                        ['A', 0, 'Type 1'],
                        ['A', 12, 'Type 2'],
                        ['B', 1, 'Type 1'],
                        ['B', 3, 'Type 1'],
                        ['B', 5, 'Type 2']],
                   columns=['Person', 'Days', 'Type'])

df['Under Day Limit'] = df['Days'] <= 3;
print df
df = df.groupby(['Person', 'Type']).agg(['count', 'sum'])

df['Percent under Day Limit'] = df['Under Day Limit']['sum'] / df['Days']['count']
print df
```

Ouput:

```
               Days     Under Day Limit     Percent under Day Limit
              count sum           count sum                        
Person Type                                                        
A      Type 1     3   5               3   2                0.666667
       Type 2     2  15               2   1                0.500000
B      Type 1     2   4               2   2                1.000000
       Type 2     1   5               1   0                0.000000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `set_index` on `Person` and `Type`
- boolean series of `Days` >= 3
- `groupby` levels in index
- `value_counts(normalize=True)`

---

```
df.set_index(['Person', 'Type']).Days.ge(3).groupby(level=[0, 1]).value_counts(True)

Person  Type    Days 
A       Type 1  False    0.666667
                True     0.333333
        Type 2  True     1.000000
B       Type 1  False    0.500000
                True     0.500000
        Type 2  True     1.000000
Name: Days, dtype: float64
```

---

***With a wee bit more formatting***

```
df.set_index(['Person', 'Type']).Days.rename('>= 3').ge(3)  \
  .groupby(level=[0, 1]).value_counts(True).unstack(fill_value=0)
```

[image]